# Why simple digital multiplexer uses OR gate to combine chip parts outs?

Tags: logic-gates, multiplexer

Why not just wire together outputs of the internal AND gates. For instance, consider the following Mux scheme:
[image]

Here outputs of the internal AND gates are combined using out OR gate to produce output, but why not to just wire them together rather than use additional chip? it seems to be a common practice to wire together multiple pins so we get ONE (or True) when at least one of the internal chips produces ONE.

Comment: You can do it in case the gate outputs are open-drain. But if `0` output in the gate is *forcing* `0` voltage, but `1` is *forcing* non-zero, then shoring these two will be catastrophic.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks, I didn't think of a short circuit...

Comment: @aryndin Also, even in the case of Eugene's comment (open-drain or open-collector outputs), this would "wire-OR" the individual outputs into a combined output. But that final, left-most gate produces a 1 as a result of either input being 0. And a wire-OR output (open-drain, again) produces a 0 as a result of either input being 0. So you'd still need an inverter.

Comment: Besides, those are NAND gates, so the final NAND sets the output polarity to same as input polarity.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `then shoring these two will be catastrophic` - can eleborate a bit more on the catastraphic part?

Comment: @liang it will produce a short circuit with high current and will burn things.